# Retrieve data from datatbase based on combo box selection

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

i am trying to display values in text box from database based on combo box change.. i'm using following code,it doesn't work please help me.. the combo change value did not pass to abc.php from combo_example.php, if i'm trying to run abc.php separately it display error like "Undefined index: combo".

combo_example.php

```
<script> src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready()function(){
$('#combo').change(function(){
$.post("abc.php",{$combo:$(this.val() )},function(result){
$("#textbox").val(result);
   });
 });
});
</script>

<form>
     <select name="combo" id="combo">
         <option value="">-- Select --</option>
         <?php  

            $query="select * from combo_example";
                $result=mysql_query($query);
                while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
               echo '<option value = "' . $row['product_name'] . '">' . 
               $row['product_name'] . '</option>';
                }
          ?>
    </select>
    <input type="textbox" id="textbox" value="<?php $row['mrp']; ?>" />
</form>
```

abc.php

```
<?php
 $product_name= $_POST['combo'];
 $rs =mysql_query("SELECT mrp FROM combo_example WHERE product_name='$product_name'");
  if($rs && mysql_num_rows($rs)){
   $row = mysql_fetch_object($rs);
   echo $row->mrp;
  }
?>
```

Comment: Is `$.post("abc.php",{$combo:$(this.val() )},function(result){` supposed to be `$.post("abc.php",{$combo:$(this).val() },function(result){`?

Comment: you should start using MySQLi or PDO_MySQL, mysql_* is deprecated

Comment: " $.post("abc.php",{$combo:$(this).val() },function(result){? " - it does not help...

Comment: While @stackErr is technically correct, it is not the source of your error and its okay to use mysql_* if you're just learning. Just make sure not to introduce any SQL injection opportunities if this project is going live.

Answer (score 0):

`mysql_fetch_array` will return an numerical array, not the associative array you need. Use `mysql_fetch_assoc`.
http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-assoc.php